# How do I validate whether a URL location exists or not?

Tags: c#, url, .net-4.0

We're hosting SSIS reports on our servers and we are storing their paths in a sql server table. From .Net, I want to be able to make sure the path entered is correct.

This should return "true" because there's a report there, for example:

```
  http://server/Reports/Pages/Viewer.aspx?%2fShopFloor%2fProduction+by+Turn&rs:Command=Render
```

This should return false.

```
http://I am an invalid location/I am laughing at you/now I'm UEEing
```

I was looking at WebRequests, but I don't know if that's the route I should be taking.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The only way to tell (assuming you've already validated the URL is a valid URL) is to make the HTTP request and see if it is successful or not.

Comment: Note though that the server might return an error page with the code HTTP 200, so you may have to check the content of the response.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: That is true, however, you really only need HEAD request because you don't need to download the whole thing.

Comment: @Guffa: Then the server is not correctly following the RFC standards.  ASP.Net should follow that standard by default.

Comment: Yes, there are many subtleties and possible optimizations.

Comment: @mellamokb: ASP.NET does follow the standars by default, but it's common to override the default error pages to present a more user friendly message, and it's not uncommon that they don't follow the standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a http `HEAD` request to the URL, which should just fetch headers. This way you dont need to download the entire page if it exists. from the returned headers(if there are any) you should be able to determine if its a correct URL or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can try making a HEAD request to validate that the resource exists.  With a HEAD request, you would only need the HTTP Code (200 = Success, 404 = Not Found) without consuming resources or excess memory to download the entire resource.  Take a look at [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class for performing the actual request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of the exact layout of your network, but if the .net application has visibility to the location the reports are stored, you could use `File.Exists()`.  Otherwise, mellamokb and red-X have the right idea.